# Given an n-arg type constructor, what are some ways to reduce the number of arguments?

Tags: haskell

For instance, for `Either`, there are two arguments `L` and `R`.

What would be several ways of constructing both of the single-parameter type constructors from Either: `Either L` and (pseudo code) `Either _ R`?

One way, I suppose, is to declare a type alias:

```
type EitherL L = Either L R -- for some fixed R
```

But are there ways to do this inline without needing to construct type aliases?

Comment: Just like the data types and functions, a type constructor has one parameter.

Comment: Is there a type-level version of `curry`/`uncurry`, then? Oh, and `flip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things don't always translate directly. In particular, you have to decide what you want to be first-class and what can be second-class.

```
-- You can do this, but it must always
-- be fully applied.
type FlipF f a b = f b a

-- This is more exciting, as it can
-- be partially applied.
newtype Flip f a b = Flip {unFlip :: f b a}
```

Now

```
Either a b = FlipF Either b a
Either a b ~= Flip Either b a
```

Currying you have multiple options too.

```
type CurryF f a b = f '(a, b)
newtype Curry f a b = Curry {unCurry :: f '(a, b)}
```

Uncurrying is a bit trickier.

```
type family UncurryF f ab where
  UncurryF f '(a, b) = f a b

data Uncurry1 f ab where
  Uncurry1 :: f a b -> f '(a, b)

newtype Uncurry2 f ab = Uncurry2
  {reCurry2 :: f (Fst ab) (Snd ab)}

type family Fst ab where
  Fst '(a, _) = a
type family Snd ab where
  Snd '(_, b) = b
```

Which uncurry you need will be somewhat application dependent.